# How to use if condition for xml node in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

These are the sample of my xml file

```
<ROOT>
    <FILE1>
        <ENGLISH_LANGUAGE>
            <ANOTHER_TAG1></ANOTHER_TAG1>
        </ENGLISH_LANGUAGE>
        <MANDARIN_LANGUAGE>
            <ANOTHER_TAG2></ANOTHER_TAG2>
        </MANDARIN_LANGUAGE>
    </FILE1>
</ROOT>
```

Let's say I want to get to  node. Can I do this by inserting **if condition** to detect xml tag node? Is that even possible..

What I have tried:

```
Dim root As String = file.DocumentElement.Name.ToString
Dim node As XmlNodeList = file.SelectNodes(root & "//FILE1")
xmlfile.GetElementsByTagName("ENGLISH_LANGUAGE")
//Logic goes here
```

What I did was to get "ENGLISH_LANGUAGE" tag, without using if condition. Is this way correct?

Edited:
I would like to add some pseudocode sample as below,

```
if xml node <ENGLISH_LANGUAGE> exists
 Do something within this xml tag
if xml node <MANDARIN_LANGUAGE> exists
 Do something within this xml tag
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to do. Your code example seems to show a concise way of obtaining the `ENGLISH_LANGUAGE` node.  What is wrong with what you are doing already?

Comment: is that the only way to get to "ENGLISH_LANGUAGE" tag? can I use something like if condition @Martin

Comment: I don't get the question either... What condition do you want to consider?

Comment: You need to put `xmlfile.GetElementsByTagName("ENGLISH_LANGUAGE")` into a variable if you want to use it because it is a function, not a sub.

Comment: @ari, can you show us in form of "pseudo code" what you mean by _use something like if condition_?

Comment: What if I would like to consider two xml tag? Do I need if condition? @AndrewMorton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Dim root As String = file.DocumentElement.Name.ToString
Dim node As XmlNodeList = file.SelectNodes(root & "//FILE1")

'GetElementsByTagName returns a collection of matching nodes 
'or an empty collection if there are no matches
Dim list As XmlNodeList = xmlfile.GetElementsByTagName("ENGLISH_LANGUAGE")

'Your logic can then be based on the fact that the collection is populated
If list.Count() > 0 Then
    'DoSomething()
End If

'Or you can perform actions on the elements within the collection
For each xmlNode As XmlNode In list
    'DoSomething()
End For
```